# How to change where the abuse email's get sent?

Tags: cpanel, vps, whm, internet-abuse

I have a domain called `example.com` which is registered with `namecheap`.

`example.com` is hosted on a VPS with the hosting company `XYZ` (make up company) with `WHM` and `cPanel`

`Nameservers` are being dealt on Cloudflare which is linked to my `XYZ` to protect my VPS's IP.

My email's (eg. `support@example.com`) are hosted on a different company called `Tmail` (make up company).

How can I forward all the abuse emails received directly to me and not to `XYZ`? I cannot host the website myself as I do not want to buy a server.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "abuse emails"? Do you literally mean emails that are sent to `abuse@example.com`?

Comment: @MrWhite I am not sure because the `XYZ` sent me an email telling me someone reported my website. However the report is completely fake and `XYZ` has already shut down my website.

Comment: How do you know they reported you via email vs through a contact form?    Do you have a copy of the email?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `XYZ` Emailed me that someone reported me. They had the reporters email, name and company. But the company hey claimed (its a huge company) to be didn't match their email domain. The email domain pointed to a godaddy landing page. It was clearly a fake report

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the domain's MX records are pointing to Tmail, that is where you need to set up either a forwarder to `support@example.com` or give `abuse@example.com` its own mailbox.

If you could create `support@` then you should be able to create `abuse@`